# Rijndael cryptography not working on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, windows-server-2012, rijndaelmanaged

I have a Windows Application (x64) that has been working fine on Winodws 7, 8 and now 10. Today we failed at running the program under a **Windows 2012 Server**. When we looked at the event log, we found an error originating from `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor()` (unfortunately the log did not give us the complete path).

I have used the *Rijndael* algorithm to for encrypting sensitive data in my program. The first thing the program does is to retrieve the encrypted config file and decrypt it in order to get all the settings. And this is where my program does not start.

This is the decrypt method in my program:

```
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message I get in the log:

> Application: Postbag.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.InvalidOperationException at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor() at
>   Common.StringCipher.Decrypt(System.String, System.String) at
>   Common.Conf..cctor() Exception Info:
>   System.TypeInitializationException at Common.Conf.get_DataProvider()
>   at Postbag.FormMain..ctor() at Postbag.Program.Main()

The new server also has the same versions of the .Net framework.

Comment: Since you aren't changing the block size, you should just replace `new RijndaelManaged()` with `Aes.Create()`.  It will produce the same output, but not have a FIPS exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The RijndaelManaged clases are not FIPS compliant and your server seems to have the Security Policy *System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing* set.

In the Knowledgebase artical ["System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing" security setting effects in Windows XP and in later versions of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811833) it says:

> Microsoft .NET Framework applications such as Microsoft ASP.NET only allow for using algorithm implementations that are certified by NIST to be FIPS 140 compliant. Specifically, the only cryptographic algorithm classes that can be instantiated are those that implement FIPS-compliant algorithms. The names of these classes end in "CryptoServiceProvider" or "Cng." Any attempt to create an instance of other cryptographic algorithm classes, such as classes with names ending in "Managed," cause an InvalidOperationException exception to occur

So either [disable the security policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSsH0.png) (from the SecPol.msc tool) or use a FIPS compliant implementation. Unfortunately Rijndael doesn't have such implementation so you might want to see if [`AesCng`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescng(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`AesCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) matches your needs because AES is the formal implementation of what started as Rijndael. Based on [the blog Is RijndaelManaged class FIPS compliant?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/11/04/is-rijndaelmanaged-class-fips-compliant/) from [Prateek Kr Dubey](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Prateek+Kr+Dubey) I conclude that data that is encrypted with `RijdaelManaged` can be decrypted with `AesCng` or `AesCryptoServiceProvider`.

To be complete I created an Encrypt method with the `RijnDaelManaged` class and adapted your code example on this line:

```
using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
```

to read

```
using (var symmetricKey = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()) // or new AesCng()
```

and was indeed able to decrypt the string.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But how can I disable the security policy?

Comment: I have linked it under *disable the security policy* but here is it as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSsH0.png

Comment: thank you for your response. let me try removing the policy from the server and try again. i don't think doing changes on the program is currently feasible since this is an on-premises solution and applying the change will demand a lot of updates. but as soon as the customer removes the policy and i will come back here.

Comment: We ended up disabling the security policy.