# Where does System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor() call come from (HASP-wrapped DLL)?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-4.0, hasp

Some settings' values in our .NET-4 application are stored encrypted [in registry].  Initial code used `AesManaged` class for that ([similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp)).  When 6 years ago we discovered that [managed implementation is not FIPS-compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939040/when-will-c-sharp-aes-algorithm-be-fips-compliant), it was replaced by `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class.

We employ Thales / Gemalto / Sentinel / Alladin HASP "wrapping" for copy protection and licensing.  As a result, if/when exception happens in wrapped code, its stacktrace does not expose neither original object names nor line numbers, making it rather difficult to unravel - unless certain discipline is followed when writing original code (like e.g. making methods short and simple).  Encryption /decryption methods are located within one of HASP-wrapped libraries.

Everything was hunky-dori until recent wrapped build failed launching(!) in FIPS-enabled environment.  Even more surprise:  as I'm trying older wrapped builds (with FIPS enabled), *they all fail*.
Granted, this may be a result of QA team skipping these paths during usual validation (*bad, but I'm not in charge of that*), but here's an unexpected observation:  **unwrapped code executes perfectly fine in the same FIPS-enabled OS!**  Huh??

Now, even more bizzare is the stacktrace, written to Windows Event Log by my `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler( )`:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'XYZ.Main.Utils' threw an exception.
    ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
        This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor()
    at 150694719.150694754.714439608(String 146425350)
    at XYZ.Main.Utils..cctor()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at XYZ.Main.Utils.SetModuleTitle(FileVersionInfo fvi)
    at XYZ.AppSuite.Program.Main(String[] saArg) in G:\DEV\XYZ\XYZ.AppSuite\Program.cs:line 316
```

This exception is very similar to [one mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300362/rijndael-cryptography-not-working-on-windows-server-2012), but indicated code does not even touch any encryption whatsoever:

```
/// <summary>Provides common and auxiliary objects and methods</summary>
public partial class    Utils
{
    /// ** Utils class is exposing global static methods and properties and does not have any constructors - at all! **
    ..

    /// <summary>Returns and sets <see cref="iBuild"/> and <see cref="dBuilt"/>, extracted from the version string (use on 'MM.NNN.*'-versioned assemblies)</summary>
    public static DateTime  GetBuildFromVersion( string sVersion )
    {
        Utils.sVersion =    sVersion;
        Utils.dBuilt =      new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 );

        string[]    saVersion=  sVersion.Split( Utils.ccTokPeriod );

        if(  saVersion.Length == 4  )
        {
            Utils.iBuild =      Convert.ToInt32( saVersion[ 2 ], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
            int     iBuilt =    Convert.ToInt32( saVersion[ 3 ], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

            Utils.dBuilt =  Utils.dBuilt.AddDays( Utils.iBuild );
            Utils.dBuilt =  Utils.dBuilt.AddSeconds( iBuilt << 1 );

            if(  TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime( Utils.dBuilt, TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges( Utils.dBuilt.Year ) )  )
                Utils.dBuilt =  Utils.dBuilt.AddHours( 1 );
        }

        return  Utils.dBuilt;
    }

    /// <summary>Sets <see cref="Utils.sModInfo"/> and <see cref="Utils.sModTitle"/> strings, based on given assembly version data</summary>
    public static void      SetModuleTitle( FileVersionInfo fvi )
    {
        try
        {
            Utils.sMachine =    Dns.GetHostName( );
        }
        catch
        {
            Utils.sMachine =    Environment.MachineName;
        }

        Utils.sModInfo =    string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId, fvi.FileDescription, fvi.Comments, fvi.FileVersion, Utils.GetBuildFromVersion( fvi.FileVersion ) );
        Utils.sModTitle =   string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId1, fvi.FileDescription, fvi.Comments, fvi.FileVersion );
        Utils.sModStart =   string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId3, Utils.idModule, Utils.iBuild, Utils.sMachine );

        if(  Utils.bService  )
            Utils.sModTitle =   string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId4, Utils.idModule, Utils.iBuild );
    }
}
```

Is it possible, that HASP-wrapping invokes its own instance of `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged..ctor()`?  As much as I understand, `AesCryptoServiceProvider` class would certainly not call `RijndaelManaged..ctor()`, am I right?
**Where does that call come from?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't use HASP, so I can't give you a 100% answer here, but there are some standard clues that we can interpret.

> `The type initializer for 'XYZ.Main.Utils' threw an exception.`

This type of error message occurs when the static initializer of a type - either a static class or a type with static members - throws an exception. Further supporting this is the following:

> `at XYZ.Main.Utils..cctor()`

The `cctor()` member is the static constructor for a type, either an explicit one that you've written or an automatic static constructor created by the compiler to handle static member initialisation.

Following the trace back up the line we have a call to an obfuscated method `150694719.150694754.714439608()` which attempts to construct an instance of `System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`... which throws the `InvalidOperationException`.

What this says to me is that your HASP implementation is attempting to use `RijndaelManaged` to handle the decryption of the static data in your class. On a machine configured for FIPS compliance this will result in the `InvalidOperationException` you're seeing, since Rijndael is not a FIPS-compliant algorithm.

Your best option is to find an updated HASP implementation that is FIPS compliant.